# In QtWebkit, how does a webpage's QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest() get invoked?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qtnetwork

I'm building a Browser application using the QtWebkit and QtNetwork modules.

Let's say that it's a requirement that each webpage only be able to access resources from only a specific folder, set aside specifically for it. In this scenario, each webpage would have some kind of ID to identify it which could be used to verify that it's accessing the correct folder.

The problem is that it's not clear how exactly the createRequest() method gets invoked. If it's a signal that's emitted or something then I would be able to intercept it and add a few parameters indicating webpage ID.

As such now the only option open to me is to create a separate QNetworkAccessManager for each QWebPage and overload the createRequest() function whereas I would really like to be able to share the QNetworkAccessManager across QWebPages.

Alternate solutions would be appreciated but generally I'm also really confused about how the createRequest() method is reached.

Reference :
[QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#createRequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a big deal to have a separate access manager for each web page. You don't have any measurements to show it to be a problem, so in a true Don Quixote fashion, you're fighting windmills and imaginary enemies :)

The `createRequest` virtual method is called by the various non-virtual request methods: `get`, `post` and `put`. It's a good example of the [non virtual interface (NVI) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern).

Comment: Accepting answer; if i ever come across measurements to the contrary i'll be sure to reopen the question. :)